# Python Compilation Error for Code implemented on Windows and trying to run on Linux

Tags: python, windows, linux, compilation

I am 100% new to Python I am bumping into this weird issue regarding compatibility when switching between Windows and Linux. I implemented a small program that implements a TCP/IP socket that communicates with a device that supports server socket over TCP/IP. My program works fine when running on Windows so I decided to test it on Linux because ultimately I want to run it on CRONTAB as a scheduled task grabbing information from a server and export to an XML. This is the weird compilation error I received when trying to compile the same code on Linux (under python 2.6, 2.7 as well as 3.1)

```
python2.7 weatherScript.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "weatherScript.py", line 1, in <module>
    import socket
File "/media/SWAP/weatherData/socket.py", line 117, in <module>
    except socket.error, msg:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'error'
```

The corresponding code segments for that would be

```
import socket

import sys

import re

from time import sleep

from xml.dom.minidom import Document
```

and

```
try:

    comSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

except socket.error, msg:

    sys.stderr.write("[ERROR] %s\n" % msg[1])

    sys.exit(1)



#connecting to weather station

try:

    comSocket.connect(())

except socket.error, msg:

    sys.stderr.write("[ERROR] %s\n" % msg[1])

    sys.exit(2)
```

Even when I remove the try-catch, the problem still persists. I am not sure whether there is any compilation incompatibility between Windows or Linux or not. Any help?

Other question would be: I want to run that python program under CRONTAB, is there any thing that I should change or include so that I can run it as a "script" or such?

Thank you so much!

Comment: It's weird that this doesn't work on Python 3.1, could you share more about your directory structure and module organization? In which directory is `weatherScript.py` located, what is your `sys.path` (or at least the part of it that corresponds to `weatherData/socket.py`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a module named `socket`, and you're trying to import the `socket` module from it. The module is obviously shadowing the builtin `socket` module (i.e. your `socket` is importing itself). If this module isn't a package, move it to a package. If/when the module is already in a package (I assume `weatherData` is a package), ensure that you have the following line before any other code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

This makes sure that all imports done from the module are *absolute*, i.e. `socket` is the top-level `socket` module, while your module is always accessed through the name `weatherData.socket` because it is a part of that package, and the two modules wouldn't clash.

Also this will only work if `weatherData` is indeed a package, if `socket` is a top-level module you need to either rename it, or move it to a package, because otherwise the names would clash regardless of whether relative imports are allowed, and you won't be able to use the two modules together.

Comment: I don't quite get your answer. with import socket, I am actually following the socket documentation on python.org, what it does (I believe) is importing the built-in socket module. The code works perfectly fine on Windows, but I don't know why it's not working on Linux.

Comment: weatherData is just a folder where I put the python program.

Comment: If you have a `socket.py` file in the directory where the program is located, you *can't* import the builtin `socket` module, because your `socket.py` is shadowing it. http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: I have another question for you sir! So my weatherData.py is supposed to write an xml file that contain the sensor readings from the weather stations. The problem I am bumping into is that: when I don't have that file, my program complied and run flawlessly, but if I have that file there, my program raises weird compilation error. I will put the error by editing my original post.